# Installing Tensorflow on Ubuntu Server 14.02

Tags: 14.04

I am brand new to Linux but was tasked with building a server and installing Tensorflow. I have the server built and python 2.7 installed.  When I run the following command I get the following output:

[image]

It looks like the install was not successful.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"Network is unreachable*" seems like a good place to start: can you ping storage.googleapis.com?

Answer (score 0):

Steeldriver's comment above is a good start.  Try opening https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/  in a browser.  You should get an XML page with a list of items.  Don't worry about the contents - the key question is whether you can successfully view the page.  If you can't, and you can post here, something's weird.  It's possible that you're behind a firewall or have a DNS problem.  A quick check for those would be to try to `ping 8.8.8.8` (google's DNS servers) and/or set your DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` to 8.8.8.8, and then retry the download.